# Can someone explain OpenCV MatOfPoint and MatOfPoint2f?

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing

I am seeing lots of references to `MatOfPoint` and `MatOfPoint2f` in OpenCV tutorials, but little to no explanation of what they actually are and what they are for. Based on what I have seen in the tutorials, I understand that they are used to store contour data, but that is about it. Could someone with a bit more knowledge on this tell me what these classes represent?

For example, I can see in these tutorials that `MatOfPoint` represents contours. I can also see that the `MatOfPoint` objects are converted to `MatOfPoint2f` to represent polygons.

- Drawing bounding rects: https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/da/d0c/tutorial_bounding_rects_circles.html#autotoc_md773
- Point polygon test: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dc/d48/tutorial_point_polygon_test.html

However the only documentation I'm seeing on these classes is what you see in the OpenCV javadocs:

- https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/javadoc/org/opencv/core/MatOfPoint2f.html
- https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/javadoc/org/opencv/core/MatOfPoint.html

I think I get the basic idea, but I am not sure where to look to get a better understanding of thse classes.

Comment: I'd suggest that you link to the documentation of those classes. helps others see what you mean.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Added references to the tutorials, and the javadocs I was able to find

Comment: Arrays of 2D coordinates, 32bit signed integers in case of `MatOfPoint`, 32bit floating point values in case of `MatOfPoint2f`. They are convenience classes used by the Java bindings to facilitate passing such data to and from the underlying C++ implementation.

Comment: @DanMašek thank you. is there any other references you can point me towards regarding these?

Comment: The [source](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/4.x/modules/core/misc/java/src/java/core%2BMatOfPoint.java) [code](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/4.x/modules/core/misc/java/src/java/core%2BMatOfPoint2f.java) | I don't really use Java, so not sure if there is some additional reference.

Comment: I'm not sure that `MatOfPoint` is integers. it might be doubles (vs float for Point2f) because `Point` holds doubles.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz On Java side (it confused me a bit as well at first). Look at the first link in my previous comment, lines 8-9 -- `CV_32S` with 2 channels. The Point/Point2f in the names refer to the C++ types (`Point` being a typedef for `Point2i`).

Comment: I see, yes, `typedef Point2i cv::Point`. I think I looked at [this](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/javadoc/org/opencv/core/MatOfPoint.html#%3Cinit%3E(org.opencv.core.Point...)) and [this](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/javadoc/org/opencv/core/Point.html) java doc, which led me to think they were holding double values.